# Trouble finding the derivative of an optimization function

Tags: regression

How can I derivate the following optimization function?

$$L=\sum_{u,i}(y_{u,i}-v_ix_u)^2+\lambda\left(\sum_i\|v_i\|_2^2+\sum_u\|x_u\|_2^2\right)$$

I just want to get the equations of the gradient descent method, so I want to get the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to $v$ and the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to $x$. This function is similar to ridge regression function.

I just know how to calculate the first of the term of the function, but I have trouble to derive the second addend of the function:

$$\delta v_i^k L=-2\sum_i(y_{u,i}-v_i x_u)x_u^k + ¿?$$
$$\delta x_i^k L=-2\sum_i(y_{u,i}-v_i x_u)v_u^k + ¿?$$

Comment: Could you help me?

Comment: You may like to first consider how to take the derivative of the norm of a vector: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296697/differentiation-of-vector-norms